# node js mysql connection

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

i have a nodejs application and want to connect the application to mysql remote host. here is my query

mysql -u user -p password -h http://xxx.xxx.com.

but getting error ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'http://xxx.xxx.com' (0).

```
and here is nodejs code both are not working

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : 'http://xxx.xxx.com',
 hostname : 'xxx.xxx.com',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'password'
 });

   connection.connect(function(err){
   });


  connection.query('SELECT * from test', function(err, rows, fields) {
   if (!err)
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
  else
  console.log('Error while performing Query.');
  });

 connection.end();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: should remove `http://`

Comment: @ben 58 after removing http its again showing errorAccess denied for user 'user'@'ip.ip.ip.ip' (using password: YES)

Comment: you should check if you enter correct username & password, and you already grant the access to user

Comment: @ben 58 yes all credentials all correct. i am able to login in browser for same ip and by same username and password.

Comment: you can connect mysql in terminal with this command `mysql -u user -p -h xxx.xxx.com`?

Comment: @ben please check above code i am using the same command in terminal mysql -u user -p password -h xxx.xxx.com . but getting same error ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'123.123.123.123' (using password: YES)

Comment: please read the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html). you properly did not enter correct password or create user improperly.